# Django/JqueryUI dialog box - How can I integreate Django with JqueryUI dialog box?

Tags: jquery, django, jquery-ui, django-forms, django-views

I want to add a feature on my Django project using [jQueryUI dialog box](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-confirmation) where when you click on a link (like a "delete" link) a jQueryUI dialog box will pop up asking you if you really want to delete that item. Then if you click on the delete button (found the jQuery dialog box) a Django function will do the delete job.

So how do I make the delete button (found the jQuery dialog box) send a post message (with  respective variables) to a Django function found in my views.py that will do the delete job?

Real examples would be truly appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Say you have something like this in your template:

```
<div id="dialog" title="Confirm delete">Are you sure?</div>
{% for object in object_list %}
# display whatever you like here
<a id="{{ object.id }}" class="delete" href="#">Delete</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Then something like this (in your `$(document).ready`) would work  -- notice how we set the callback function that the dialog calls when the delete button is pressed (using the dialog's [option method](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#method-option)) in the `click` handler:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: false
});
$("a.delete").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $("#dialog").dialog('option', 'buttons', {
        "Delete": function() {
            $.post({
                url: {% url myapp.views.delete %},
                data: {'id': id},
                success: function() {
                   # whatever you like, some fancy effect that removes the object
                }
            });
            $(this).dialog("close");
        },
        "Cancel": function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    });
    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Any ideas how to add an ID to the dialog "delete" button? I have multiple forms on the same page and the way I make the distinction from what form the post request came from is by identifying the button id like this: if 'my_button_id' in request.POST: ...then do something...

Answer (score 2):

You should also consider [Aprise](http://thrivingkings.com/apprise/). It is lovely, uses jQuery, is easy to use, and is very small (3k).

```
apprise('Hello now?', {'verify':true});
```

[image: aprise dialog]